Will ceramic bowl or clay serve as epoxy mold?
I have inherited some two-part epoxy resin from a leaving shop mate, and got an idea for it. Would like to avoid even moderate expense buying or making a silicone mold.
There is this kind of pudding bowl of glazed ceramic around, as well as fine-grained modeling clay. Can I use either of those to pour into and shatter after curing, given the piece will need smoothing anyway?
The target size is about 10x7x2 cm plus bevel.

The glazed ceramic bowl is not even worth trying if you want to separate the epoxy after curing. Epoxy will most likely stick to the glazing. You could spray the inside with mold release, but I expect complications and sticking if you miss a small area.
The modeling clay can be removed from the epoxy after curing (and I've personally done this already), but it will leave a matte surface and probably some clay residue on the epoxy. It will definitely need sanding and/or polishing and in the worst case you'll be smearing around a fine film of clay that gunks up the sand paper, but overall this is still a viable option.
For your own safety: only use the modeling clay inside  another container that can catch any spilled epoxy. It's hard to get the modeling clay 100% leak-free and epoxy will find tiny gaps to leak through. Also observe the safety instructions of your epoxy (wear gloves, work in a very well ventilated area, ect). Epoxy is a hazardous substance and can cause life long health issues.

Thank you, also for the health tip. Does it make sense to seal the clay mold with lacquer for smoothness, like clear water-based acrylic?

I think epoxy will stick to lacquer, but different products can behave differently. You could seal it with simple construction silicone by smearing the silicone inside and then smoothing it with your fingers dipped in some water with lots of dish washing soap. Also certain plastics like Polyethylene and PVC don't stick to epoxy. I think acrylic sheets are often used for mold making. Or use a disposable empty food container or something similar. You can find inspiration by searching for "diy epoxy mold".

It's true, I put a speck of epoxy on clear acrylic, and it diffused in and yellowed it.
